# To unwrap the CBOR decoded Data in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, bluetooth, cbor

I have following Struct in Swift

```
struct SerializableRequest {        
  var r: Int
  var m: String
  var d: String
  var b: [UInt8]
}
```

Then I make a instance of a struct:

```
SerializableRequest(r: 1, m: "c", d:"l", b: [42, 24] )
```

and encode it using CBOR which gives: [164, 97, 109, 97, 99, 97, 98, 66, 42, 24, 97, 100, 97, 108, 97, 114, 1]

Now I want to decode it again back to Struct using above byte array but on decoding it produces output

```
([SwiftCBOR.CBOR.utf8String("d"): SwiftCBOR.CBOR.utf8String("l"), 
  SwiftCBOR.CBOR.utf8String("r"): SwiftCBOR.CBOR.unsignedInt(1), 
  SwiftCBOR.CBOR.utf8String("b"): SwiftCBOR.CBOR.byteString([42, 24]), 
  SwiftCBOR.CBOR.utf8String("m"): SwiftCBOR.CBOR.utf8String("c")]
)
```

How one can get Struct using PATTERN MATCHING using https://github.com/myfreeweb/SwiftCBOR

Answer (score 0):

I've read SwiftCBOR docs and I suppose you could use it like this :

```
struct SerializableRequest {
    var r: Int
    var m: String
    var d: String
    var b: [UInt8]

    init(cborArr: [CBOR]) {

        for (i, val) in cborArr.enumerated() {
            if i == 0 {
               //
            } else if i == 1 {
                if case let CBOR.utf8String(string) = val {
                    m = string
                }
            } else if (i == 2) {
                // and so on
            }
        }
    }
}
```

as you can see above, I know that at first position there is a String, so I enumerate through the cborArr, checks the each item position and trying to decode value(because i expect that at the 1 position will be String). Also, you could use CodableCBORDecoder, [check this out](https://github.com/myfreeweb/SwiftCBOR/blob/master/Tests/SwiftCBORTests/CodableCBORDecoderTests.swift)

Answer (score 0):

try this simple example

```
import Foundation
import SwiftCBOR

struct S: Codable {
    let integer: Int
    let string: String
    let byteArray: [UInt8]
}

let s1 = S(integer: 1, string: "Hello, World", byteArray: [1,2,255])


do {
    let encoder = CodableCBOREncoder()
    // encoded Data
    let data = try encoder.encode(s1)
    
    let decoder = CodableCBORDecoder()
    // decoded S
    let s2 = try decoder.decode(S.self, from: data)
    
    print(s2)
    // S(integer: 1, string: "Hello, World", byteArray: [1, 2, 255])

    
} catch {
    print(error)
}
```